# Overloading the << operator. Where/to whom is the reference returned?

Tags: c++

comp c;
...
cout<< c;

the overloaded operator<< function returns a reference. In this case where is it returned or who collects it. What is the purpose of returning a reference ?

```
class comp
    {
      int re,im;

      public: comp(){re=0;im=0;}
            comp(int a,int b){re=a;im=b;}
            void show(){cout<<"\n"<<im<<"+i"<<re<<"\n\n";}
            comp operator *(comp a)
            {
              comp temp;
              temp.re=(re+a.re) - (im*a.im);
              temp.im=(im*a.re) + (re*a.im);
              return temp;
            }
      friend ostream & operator<<(ostream& dout,complex & )

    };
    ostream& operator << (ostream &dout, comp &a)
     {
       dout<< a.re;
       dout<< "+i";
       dout<<a.im;
       return dout;
     }

    int main()
    {
     comp a(1,2),b(2,3),c;
     c=a*b;
     c.show();
     cout<< c;
     return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A chain of `<<` operators, like `a << b << c << d`, is parsed by C/C++ into `(((a << b) << c) << d)`, which is the same as

```
a.operator<<(b).operator<<(c).operator<<(d)
```

The "result" of each `<<` is the LHS of the next `<<`; thus, to make this chaining work, the `ostream` must be returned from each `operator<<`.

Comment: Thanks.Agreed. What happens to the final reference that's  returned?

Comment: @Coder: like any unused return value, it is discarded.

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression that unused return values genarate errors